# python context manager one liner

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop, contextmanager

Is it possible to write a one-liner `with` context manager in python?

Something like:

```
with open('xml_file.xml') as file: file.write('<fave_food>filled dhal puri roti</fave_food>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to open the file for writing if you want to write in it.